# jQuery dataTables - how to render id from fnRender function

Tags: jquery, datatables

In dataTables, how to render id from `fnRender` function

```
function filltable() {
        var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler.aspx?action=get&getmethod=activity",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "DesignationID" },
                { "mDataProp": "DesignationName" },
                { "mDataProp": "DesignationShortName"},
                { "mDataProp": null,
              "sTitle": "Activity-Action",
              "bSearchable": false,
              "bSortable": false,
              "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                  return "<a  href='#' name='lnkEditActivity' id='" + oObj.aData["DesignationID"] + "' class='sepV_a' title='Edit'><i class='icon-pencil'></i></a> <a href='#' title='Delete' name='lnkDeleteActivity' id='" + oObj.aData["DesignationID"] + "'><i class='icon-trash'></i></a>";
              }
          }
    ]
        });
  }
```

How To Grab id from `fnRender` Function..I am not able to grab id from `fnRender` function..help